# soapUI with Maven from IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, log4j, soapui

I have a soapUI 4.5.2 project that I run using Maven 3.0.5 through IntelliJ 12. This actually works great. All of the tests are run and I have my pom file configured to write log files exactly where I want them. The issue that I am running into is this. soapUI is writing a lot of data to the console and I can't seem to trim that back. I have tried my own log4j settings:

```
# Print info for the root logger
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.header=ERROR
log4j.logger.httpclient.wire.content=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=ERROR
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Print the date in ISO 8601 format
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

But soapUI / Maven still produces debug output to the console. For example:

09:47:44,096 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: PUT /template/xyz/ HTTP/1.1
09:47:44,722 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
09:47:44,732 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection shut down

I have edited the soapui-log4j.xml file to only print ERROR but that doesn't help. It could be that I have the correct edits but I don't know how to tell Maven / soapUI to use this file from my pom file in IntellIj. Any ideas on how to stop all of the console output?

Here is my pom file:

```
<groupId>com.xyz.soapui</groupId>
<artifactId>apitesting</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<name>apitesting</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3.0.5</maven>
</prerequisites>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>eviwarePluginRepository</id>
        <url>http://www.eviware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>mvnPluginRepository</id>
        <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/mule/dependencies/maven2/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>codehausPluginRepository</id>
        <url>https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/org/codehaus/mojo/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.redfish4ktc.soapui</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-soapui-extension-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1.4</version>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                    <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.jgoodies</groupId>
                    <artifactId>looks</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.fifesoft</groupId>
                    <artifactId>rsyntaxtextarea</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.7</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <runnerType>PRO</runnerType>
                <projectFile>${basedir}/src/test/resources/apitesting-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/soapui-reports</outputFolder>
                <exportAll>true</exportAll>
                <reportFormat>HTML</reportFormat>
                <coverage>false</coverage>
                <printReport>true</printReport>
                <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                <testFailIgnore>true</testFailIgnore>
                <settingsFile>/home/xyz/soapui-settings.xml</settingsFile>
                <projectProperties>
                    <value>pmessage=Project Property</value>
                </projectProperties>
                <globalProperties>
                    <value>gmessage=Global Property</value>
                </globalProperties>
                <soapuiProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>soapui.logroot</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/soapui-logs/</value>
                    </property>
                </soapuiProperties>
                <inputProject/>
                <outputProject/>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Thank you!

Comment: is your log4j config file named `soapui-log4j.xml` and located at projectBaseDir ?

Comment: Ok! I have moved my soapui-log4j.xml file to the projectBaseDir and that seems to work. Here is some output: Configuring log4j from [/home/xyz/Documents/Source/xyzapitesting/soapui-log4j.xml]. Is there a way to also ignore the occasional stack trace that comes up due to java.lang.NullPointerException? This occurs after soapUI closes a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According [plugin doc](https://github.com/redfish4ktc/maven-soapui-extension-plugin/wiki/Tips#providing-your-own-log4j-configuration-file) you can override the log4j config for soapUI :

> You can also override the default log configuration by providing a 'soapui-log4j.xml' file in the project base directory. This works both with smartbear plugins (open source and pro) and maven-soapui-extension-plugin.

So be sure to use the correct filename, location and format (xml... but it may also work with a 'soapui-log4j.properties' : I didn't try)

Comment: Adding soapui-log4j.xml to the projectBaseDir squared me away. Thank you! And spelling it correctly helped too... :)